# Does the realm database use "non-exempt encryption" by default?

Tags: realm

The license text for the realm database says (under *export compliance*):

> You understand that the Software may contain cryptographic functions that may be
>   subject to export restrictions, [...]

If I am not using an encrypted database but just the standard, out of the box database, is the Realm engine by itself using non-exempt encryption?

In other words: Is it safe to set the `ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption` key to false or answer accordingly when asked in iTunesConnect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a lawyer, but in this case, yes, it should be safe.

iOS itself implements export-controlled encryption features (even simply calling an `https` URL technically counts), but declaring your export compliance depends on:

1. Whether you're actually adopting and using these encryption features in your app.
2. If so, what is the nature of the data/functionality that you are actually encrypting.

So in this case, if you're not using the encryption features of Realm, it's not necessary to declare export compliance exemption specifically for it.

That being said, I'd still encourage you to review the other features of your app. While Realm itself may not require export exemption, other features in your app might. Thankfully, the vast majority of iOS consumer app categories these days are [covered](https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/policy-guidance/encryption/encryption-faqs#15) under the exemption, so it's not often necessary to file an ERN.